# Export data to pdf in Laravel downloading only 2 pages irrespective of data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have huge amount of data in my DB. But when I try to export data to pdf in Laravel only 2 pages are downloading.

```
 $members = DB::table('members')->where('id_card_issued',0)->get(); 
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.myPDF', compact('members'));
 return $pdf->download('id_card.pdf');
```

I want all the data to be downloaded. But now only getting last 2 data in my database table

Comment: Have you checked to see if `DB::table('members')->where('id_card_issued',0)->get()` returns all the records you require? Try running `dd($members);` and seeing what is returned

Comment: yes, I tried printing all the data and am getting the required data

Comment: If you are on localhost then you might have a problem in your `php.ini` `max_execution_time` or `memory_limit` try to increase these limits and then restart the server and try again. It may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do to download large files from the server, I have changed the below settings in php.ini file in mine to do so :

```
Upload_max_filesize  - 1500 M
Max_input_time  - 1000
Memory_limit    - 640M
Max_execution_time -  1800
Post_max_size - 2000 M
```

Comment: I did not get the answer

Comment: Answer for what?

Comment: I tried with this answer. But I got the same result as above